# Filtering DateTime Column of DataTable Causes FormatException

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, filtering

I have a `DataTable dt` bound to a `DataGridView`. I have been filtering the data in this grid at run-time using the standard query syntax. However, for a known `DateTime` column in this `DataTable` the query

```
DataRow[] rowArray = dt.Select("DOB >= #01/01/97# AND DOB <= #31/01/97#");
```

But this is throwing a FormatException with the message:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I have tried changing the above to

```
DataRow[] rowArray = dt.Select("DOB >= #01/01/1997# AND DOB <= #31/01/1997#");
```

But this gave the same error. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it seems I am filtering correctly. I can confirm that the `DataTable` column 'DOB' is indeed a `DateTime` type.

**What is wrong with the filter statement?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The format depends to your current culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think about is the Locale. This seems you use GB Locale. Try this.

```
CultureInfo myCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-gb");
dt.Locale = myCultureInfo;
DataRow[] rowArray = dt.Select("DOB >= #01/01/1997# AND DOB <= #31/01/1997#");
```

Comment: This has not helped!? The culture was in fact 'en-GB' by default.

Comment: @Killercam I usually use ' instead of # in the filter expression. It always works. Could you try this one more time? DataRow[] rowArray = dt.Select("DOB >= '01/01/1997' AND DOB <= '31/01/1997'");

Answer (score 1):

Just pass two `DateTime` variables into your `Select` statement like this: *(based on your comment regarding inputting the date in text boxes, I also added some data validation)*

```
DateTime startDate;
DateTime endDate;

var isValidStartDate = DateTime.TryParse(txtStartDate.Text, out startDate);
var isValidEndDate = DateTime.TryParse(txtEndDate.Text, out endDate);

if (isValidStartDate && isValidEndDate)
{
    var rowArray = dt.Select(
        string.Format("DOB >= #{0}# AND DOB <= #{1}#", startDate, endDate));

    // do something with rowArray
}
else
{
    // uh-oh...
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to filter the data by typing in to a `TextBox` at run-time so preferably I want to avoid conversions and just use the string literal... I know I could convert and convert back but this should not be necessary. I might try it just to see if it fixes the issue though.

Comment: I see the point of validation here, but this is definately not working as it should be. I don;t really want to have to handle dates with in strings seperately but merely pass what selection the user specifes streight to the filter. Otherwise I will have to `Regex reg = new Regex(@"#[^#]+#");`, `Trim('#')` et al. etc. etc. Any idea why the basic filter is still not working?

Comment: This is crazy. I have implemented what you have above, the `Select(...)` STILL throws `FormatException` even though they are recognized as valid `DateTime`s!?

Comment: Crazy, same thing. I have no idea what the fudge is happening here. I have just written a method to change the `DateTimeMode` for each `DateTime` column which is currently `UnspecifedLocal` to `Local`, this also has not helped. Gad'Dang. Thanks for your time and help.